# Checking the validity of Bivariate Distribution function

Tags: probability-distributions, reference-request, bivariate-distributions

Which of the following is /are bivariate Distribution function:

1. $F(x,y)=\begin{cases}
     0 & \text{ if } x+y<0\\ 
     1 & \text{ if } x+y\geq0
      \end{cases}$
2. $F(x,y)=\begin{cases}
      1-e^{-2x} & \text{ if } x>0,y\geq1 \\ 
      \frac{1-e^{-x}}{2} & \text{ if } x>0,0<y<1 
      \end{cases}$

**My approach**

All the conditions of Distribution function is fulfilled in the first one as $x\rightarrow \infty,y\rightarrow \infty$, then $F\rightarrow 1$ and when both values tends to $-\infty$, the distribution goes to zero.

But in the second, if we use these conditions, then  the distribution is not defined for negative values of x and y. Then, how do we go about checking the conditions of Distribution function.

Any help?

EDIT.1 Also, if anyone can give me reference material for these type of problems, it would be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: @drhab yes, sorry. My bad. Let me correct it.

Comment: You must interpret 2) as the question: "can a distribution function $F:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ satisfy the mentioned the conditions?"

Comment: @drhab I need practice in Bivariate Distribution Function problems. Can you please suggest some references from where I can study these topics in detail. This given Problem has been asked in my exam.

Comment: I am afraid not. It has been ages ago that I checked whether a bivariate function could be a distribution function. An awkward subject on its own (often only to be met on an exam, not in probability theory itself) and in my view not very important. I suggest that you edit your question and add your request for a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Help on 1)

Let $z\in\mathbb R$.

Now if $F$ is a indeed a distribution function and $P$ denotes the corresponding probability then $P((-\infty,z]\times(-\infty,-z])=F(z,-z)=1$

It can be shown however that $P((-\infty,z]\times(-\infty,-z]-\{(z,-z)\})=0$

This because $(-\infty,z]\times(-\infty,-z]-\{(z,-z)\}$ can be written as: $$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[(-\infty,z-\frac1n]\times(-\infty,-z]\cup(-\infty,z]\times(-\infty,-z-\frac1n]\right]$$

where $P((-\infty,z-\frac1n]\times(-\infty,-z])=F(z-\frac1n,-z)=0$ and $P((-\infty,z]\times(-\infty,-z-\frac1n])=F(z,-z-\frac1n)=0$.

This together leads to $P(\{(z,-z)\}=1$ for every $z\in\mathbb R$ which is absurd.

So we conclude that $F$ is not a distribution function.